# Look for DTSX project in SQL job agent?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I use DTSX project (in C#) as a step in agent MSSQL2012 agent job.
I work with one of them. It is possible to find out in which job, in which step was used my DTSX project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you can find all SSIS job steps using a specific package like this:

```
select
    j.name,
    js.step_id,
    js.command
from 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    on js.job_id = j.job_id
where 
    js.subsystem = 'SSIS' and 
    js.command like '%MyPackage%'
```